# Looking of console-friendly equivalent to show() that wraps text within columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I frequently use dataframe.show() to output tabular data to the console in a human-readable manner. Can anyone suggest an equivalent to show() that supports word-wrap within columns?

```
Seq(
  ("a very large amount of text", 256),
  ("a really large amount of text", 15015),
  ("a an absolutely enormous amount of text, too much to contain in one line", 2131)
).toDF("word", "count").show(false)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|word                                                                    |count| +------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|a very large amount of text                                             |256  |
|a really large amount of text                                           |15015|
|a an absolutely enormous amount of text, too much to contain in one line|2131 | +------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+

I would prefer something that will return:

+-----------------------------------------------+-----+
|word                                           |count|
+-----------------------------------------------+-----+
|a very large amount of text                    |256  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-----+
|a really large amount of text                  |15015|
+-----------------------------------------------+-----+
|a an absolutely enormous amount of text,       |131  |
|too much to contain in one line                |     |
+-----------------------------------------------+-----+
```